# sonar-scanner with java project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

I have java project (non -gradle ) and want to test sonarQube. So, I install sonar-scanner for mac (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/)  How do I use it to scan my Java project?

my project structure is:
src->main-java->com->mycompany>packageName1->[java files]
src->main-java->com->mycompany>packageName2 ->[java files]

This is what I have tried

sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=WT-QA-API-IS  -Dsonar.java.binaries=. -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mycompany.com -Dsonar.login= xxxx -Dexclusions=bin

It does not scan the java files in the sub-folders

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing sonar analysis of a Java Project, you need to provide the compiled .class files, not the java files in `sonar.java.binaries`.

Compiled .class files are generally present in target/ folder.
You can either give the relative path like `/target/classes/*` or `**/*`

Sample example:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=WT-QA-API-IS -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/* -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mycompany.com -Dsonar.login= xxxx -Dsonar.exclusions=bin
```

More details you can find here in [JAVA| SonarQube Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/)